# Changing a variable in a list does not affect the list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I've been attempting to write some code to tune variables in my chess program, and I found that this code doesn't do what I expect it to do at all.

```
import random

# Knight value, bishop value, rook value, queen value
values = [300, 300, 500, 900]

e1vals = values
e2vals = values    

# Add a gaussian distributed random number to it
deltas = []
for i in range(0, len(values)):
    x = random.gauss(0, 20)
    deltas.append(x)

for i in range(0, len(values)):
    e1vals[i] = values[i] + deltas[i]
    e2vals[i] = values[i] - deltas[i]

print(e1vals)
print(e2vals)
```

Intuitively, the code here should simply add or subtract the values in deltas to e1vals and e2vals, but instead it doesn't make any change other than casting values to float.

I'm using Python 3.5.1 if that makes any difference.

Comment: @GWW No, I'm pointing out that adding to the list variables isn't changing the list.

Comment: @ZirconiumX Exactly, See the dupe and create a new copy of the list by using `e1vals = values[:]`.

Comment: @Zirconium `e1values = values[:]` and `e2values = values[:]` presuming `e1vals` is supposed to be `e1values` etc..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham They're supposed to represent the piece values for engine 1 and engine 2

Comment: @ZirconiumX, I meant more along the lines that I don't see those names define anywhere

Comment: Oops, looks like I made a copy/paste error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `e1values` and `e2values` refer to the *same* list. So all your code does is add a value to each item in the list, then subtract it again, leaving you with the original value.

Comment: Right, so e1values and e2values are references, not copies?

Comment: Correct, assignment always creates a reference.